# form:errors doesn't render on jsp

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-form

I have  following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/member/createCompany/addParams", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String setCompanyParams(
            @ModelAttribute MyDto myDto,
            @RequestParam(value = "g-recaptcha-response") String recapchaResponse,
            HttpSession session, Principal principal, Model model) throws Exception {

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<MyDto>> violations;        
        if(condition1){
               violations = validator.validate(myDto, ValidationGroup1.class);
        } else {
              violations = validator.validate(myDto);
        }
        if (violations.size() > 0) {
            return "member/createCompany/addParams";
        }
        ...
}
```

MyDto class:

```
class MyDto {
    @NotEmpty
    String companyName;    

    @NotEmpty(groups = ValidationGroup1.class)
    String generatedPassword;
}
```

and following jsp:

```
   <form:form commandName="myDto" id="addParams" action="/member/createCompany/addParams" method="POST">
                        <form:errors cssClass="error"  path="companyName"/><br/>
                        <form:input type="text" id="companyName" path="companyName" name="companyName" maxlength="255" value="${campaign.campaignName}"/><br/>

                        <form:errors cssClass="error"  path="generatedPassword"/><br/>
                        <form:input path="generatedPassword" type="text" id="generatedPassword" name="generatedPassword" value="${generatedPassword}" />
                         ... 
   </form:form>
```

When I submit form I see that

`violations.size() > 0` is true

but when I see rendered page I dont see error messages.
 What the problem?

Comment: I think you need a BindingResult parameter and add your violations to it

Comment: Can you advise code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039116/spring-mvc-validation-post-redirect-get-partial-updates-optimistic-concurren/29039117#29039117

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29608187/3545273) to you previous question, that's not the way Spring MVC validations work.

Spring MVC comes with a lot of magic ... provided you follow its rules. For the `<form:errors .../>` tags to work, you must have an `Errors` object in the response tied to the `ModelAttribute` object. It happens automagically if you put one `BindingResult` as a method parameter immediately after the model attribute (see ref<sup>ed</sup> answer)

Unfortunately, when you do that, Spring will validate every field, which is not what you want, without any simple way to ignore errors on some fields. So you could :

- put no *automatic* validator through an @InitBinder annotated method
- and either

  - explicitely reject fields by doing a manual validation (or depending of your *`violation`*) - a bit manual, but robust method
  - use a `SpringValidatorAdapter` around your JSR-303 validator as it can use validation groups as validation hints through its `SmartValidator` interface and explicitely calls its method `void validate(Object target,
          Errors errors,
          Object... validationHints)` in your controller.

Anyway, I strongly advice you not to create a validator for each request, but create it as a bean and inject it in your controller.